# xcode, UIScrollView keep looping scroll animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Objective

- trying to make a scrollview, it able to auto scroll to left. after complete will auto scroll to right. and repeat.

The scroll animation keep looping and keep go on the "AfterDone" method even the animation not yet complete.

```
- (void) afterAnimationStops{
float newOffSetX = _tableview.bounds.size.width-wContentBgImg;
NSLog(@"Inside AutoMove > %d",LzAutoMove);
if(leftright==1 && LzAutoMove==0)
{
    NSLog(@"Come In > 1");
    LzAutoMove = 1;
    leftright = 2;
    [UIScrollView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
                         [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
                         LzcurrentLocation = (-newOffSetX);
                         [imgCell.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake((-newOffSetX), 0)];
                         [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             [self afterDone];
                         }
                     }];
}else{
    if(LzAutoMove==0){
    NSLog(@"Come In > 2");
        LzAutoMove = 1;
        leftright = 1;
        [UIScrollView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                                    delay:0.0f
                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                               animations:^{
                                   [UIScrollView beginAnimations:@"scrollAnimation" context:nil];
                                   [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
                                   LzcurrentLocation = 0;
                                   [imgCell.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
                                   [UIScrollView commitAnimations];
                                   //[UIScrollView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterDone)];
                               }
                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                   if (finished) {
                                       [self afterDone];
                                   }
                               }];

    }

}
}

- (void) afterDone{
    NSLog(@"Done");
    LzAutoMove = 0;
    [self afterAnimationStops];
}
```

i still learning how to use the "animation completed" method, is that any one can show me where i doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I can see a never-ending recursion, which can lead to out of memory

Comment: @bhargavg, user able to interrupt it. so without user interrupt, it will be never end.

Comment: My bad, it wont cause any recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` flags for your animation option, the animation will auto repeat and reverse to original state after each completion.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                            delay:0.0f
                          options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                       animations:^{
                           [imgCell.scrollview setContentOffset:contentOffset];
                       }
                       completion:^(BOOL finished){
                       }];
```